# Within OpenCV,some methods exist in c++ only,how to do same thing in python?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

For example:

```
  BackgroundSubtractorMOG2::setShadowThreshold(double threshold)
```

in python

```
cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=True)
```

will return an object,but this object hasn't any method,so how to set shadow threshod in python?

Answer (score 0):

When execute `help(cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2())`, it shows the methods available on `Python` bindings. `setShadowThreshold()` is there. Create a MOG2 object and invoke the method.

```
 |  setShadowThreshold(...)
 |      setShadowThreshold(threshold) -> None
```

Hope this help.